# How to exclude ToolBar from the composite

Tags: java, swt

I have created a User Interface in SWT and I have a text box and a ToolItem in my composite. I am able to exclude the text box from the UI by using `GridData.exclude` and `setVisible` method of Text control when I select **Disable Text box** SWT button by using the below code.

```
buttonOne.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) { 
        GridData griddata = (GridData) txtInput.getLayoutData();
        griddata.exclude = state;
        txtInput.setVisible(!state);
        txtInput.getParent().layout(false);
    }
});
```

But I am not able to do the same with ToolBar. Now I have to make the Toolbar vanish/exclude which contains the tool item **PUSH item** from the user interface when I select the **Disable ToolItem** SWT button and bring it back If I select another SWT button.

[image]

Comment: Toolbar should work just the same. Show us a [mcve] that we can actually test.

Comment: In my view it, griddata.exclude will not work with  `ToolItem` as it not swt control